# Difference between (quote string) and "string"

Tags: string, symbols, print

Experiment on interative ielm

```
ELISP> (print 'list)

list

list
ELISP> (print "list")

"list"

"list"
```

Any differences with the two results? by the way, one extra times printed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`'list` and `"list"` are different datatypes:

```
ELISP> (type-of 'list)
symbol
ELISP> (type-of "list")
string
```

Note that they even show up differently in your example -- it's the difference between `list` and `"list"`.

But why do they show up twice? Well, because the REPL displays anything printed out, but *also* prints out the return value of the s-expression. For example:

```
ELISP> 3
3 (#o3, #x3, ?\C-c)
ELISP> "I'm being returned!"
"I'm being returned!"
```

So if we use [progn](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/progn.html), which runs all of its arguments and returns the last one, we can see the difference between a *printed* value and a returned one:

```
ELISP> (progn (print "I'm being printed") 'not-printed)

"I'm being printed"

not-printed
ELISP> (progn 'not-printed (print "I'm being printed"))

"I'm being printed"

"I'm being printed"
```

See how in the first example, the printed value shows up, followed by the not printed one? `'not-printed` only ever shows up because it's *returned*; in the second example, we don't see `'not-printed` ever show up! We see `"I'm being printed"` twice -- first printed, then returned.